# Proving R is not an integral domain.

Tags: ring-theory

So I have $(x^4 + 2x^3 +3x^2 +2x +1) + I$ and I'm wanting to show that this is not an integral domain. I know that I have to use the principal ideal which is $x^3 + 1$ and somehow get it into a form that involves the principal ideal to show that it's not the integral domain but I'm not sure how to. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Using the the ring is $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/I$, I think this can then be simplified to $(x^4 +3x^2 +1) + I$ but I'm not sure if that's right and if it is right, I'm stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: What is the ring $R$ here (see you title)?

Comment: The ring is R=F2[x]/I

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb F_2$, namely we have
$$
f=x^4 + 2x^3 +3x^2 +2x +1=(x^2 + x + 1)^2.
$$
Hence there are zero divisors and the quotient ring $\Bbb F_2[x]/(f)$ is not an integral domain. For the same reason,
$$
\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^3+1)
$$
has zero divisors, i.e., because $x^3+1$ is reducible over $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: I was told to first evaluate [(x^2 + x +1) + I]^2 and then use this to determine that R isn't a integral domain

Comment: I think that they want us to use the principal ideal to show this which is why I'm confused as previous examples they've used have done this

Comment: But the principal ideal in this case is X^3 + 1 so how does that equal x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 +2x +1 ?

Comment: The question tells me that the principal ideal is X^3 + 1 so how can that not be the principal ideal?

Comment: I'm very confused to be honest. I'm supposed to be showing that R which is F2[X]/I where I=x^3 +1 is not an integral domain and yet you're telling me that I isn't X^3 +1... but then I wouldn't be proving what the question is asking

Comment: Yes the question is to 'Evaluate [(x^2 + x + 1) + I]^2 and use this to show R (=F2[x]/I) is not an integral domain.

Comment: I am also very confused about your question, I am sorry. You should have defined $R$ and $I$ more clearly. I had to ask you this, remember?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I'm new on here, I only joined yesterday.

Comment: Now that you know the question, are you able to help?

Comment: I is the principal ideal generated by X^3 + 1

Comment: I've explained that we need to use the evaluation of [(x^2 + x + 1) + I] and the principal ideal to show it's not an integral domain

Comment: But the x^4 +..... comes from the {(x^2 + x + 1) + I]^2 that's the whole point of the question first we evaluate [(x^2 .....]^2 which gives us X^4 ...... so we have to find out how the x^4 comes from the X^3 + 1 but I'm unsure on how to do this

Comment: I don't know what to do, I feel even more confused than when I initially asked the question but it's fine. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 1):

All you have to check is whether the polynomial you wrote is irreducible or not. The polynomial you wrote modulo $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)^2$, obviously i used the “freshman’s dream”.

Comment: I was told to evaluate [(X^2 + x +1) + I]^2 initially and then use the answer to that to show determine R isn't an integral domain and I think that you need to use the principal ideal to do so